# Javascript setTimeOut causing Access Denied Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe

I have the following scenario:

Main.aspx Page ---> AJAX Modal PopUp ---> iFrame ---> ASP.Net Master Page ---> Nested.aspx Page

On the Nested.aspx page I have the following JQuery script:

```
             window.onload = function () 
            {
              setTimeout(function(){

              // Some Code here

              setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);
              }, 100);
            }
```

When I close the Modal PopUp everything will work fine for a few seconds and then I get a javascript error "SCRIPT5: Access is denied".

What I believe is happening is that the timer continues to run after the page has been closed and it is trying to access the form that no longer exists outside the iFrame hence the "Access Denied" error.

Any ideas how to stop the timer after the Modal is closed? I suspect I have to do it via javascript in the Nested.aspx page window.unload function, but not sure exactly how?

Comment: Are all the pages coming from the same domain?

Answer (score 1):

You code has nothing to do with JQuery, That being said, Here you go:

```
var timer1,timer2;
window.onload = function () 
{
    timer1 = setTimeout(function(){

        // Some Code here

        timer2 = setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);
    }, 100);
}

// add this where needed (form close?)
clearTimeout(timer1);
clearTimeout(timer2);
```

You could also add an `if` statement in your `setTimeout` function to check if the form is actualy there.

Comment: There is no specific form. When I said form I just basically meant the page being hosted by the iFrame.

Comment: When I close the modal hosting the iFrame the Nest.aspx pages windows.unload function doesn't get called.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It didn't quite solve the problem but led me in the right direction. +1

Comment: it dosent have to be on `window.unload` function, i made the timers global, so basicly they could be closed from the same function that closes the modal.

Answer (score 0):

OK, to fix this I changed from using the recursive setTimeout() method to using setInterval() which is inherently recursive and it solved the problem.

Comment: `setInterval` as you said, is recursive, therfor it might raise more problems (the code will run every x milliseconds recusivly) and might re-run your code. also, you might have to use `clearInterval`.